# How do I stop this for loop at n?

Tags: java, loops, sum

Trying to get the summing to stop at 100. When I run the program as it is, it sums all the way to 5050.

```
public class IntSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int n = 100;

        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            sum = sum+i;
            System.out.println("Sum = " +sum);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The sum of the numbers 1 through 100 is 5050.

Comment: There is a formula for this: `(n * (n + 1)) / 2` if you want to sum up consecutive numbers without a for-loop

Answer (score 2):

The for loop can use any boolean expression as the check, it doesn't always have to be the format of `i < x`. For example:

```
for (int i = 1; sum < 100; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if`-statement inside your loop. If the `sum` exceeds 100, `break` to `for`-loop